How to fix wrongly stickered Rubik's cube
I have an edge piece that has the same color (white) on both side. I think it's unsolvable now. Should I swap the stickers? How would I know which one to exchange it with?

Is the only anomaly that there is one edge piece that has a white sticker where another coloured sticker should go?  Or do you also have another duplicated piece? (ie, two edge pieces that are both green/orange and there is no green/white)

If there are 9 white stickers and 9 of each other , there is most probably at least one piece sticked with a wrong colour on one side instead of white. Check it.

If you have a white sticker on both sides of an edge piece, and you can't tell any difference between the two, then these things are for certain:

It is definitely impossible to solve the cube.
The easiest way to determine which stickers you should switch is to try and solve the cube as far as you can get it.

On a regular cube, you can determine which pieces you should have by checking the centres (which are fixed relative to each other), and then considering if you have a fitting piece for each corner and edge position on the finished cube. That should give you a good idea on which pieces have the wrong stickers on them.
However, that's not quite enough: if you swap the wrong white sticker, you end up with a cube that has all the correct pieces, but now one of your edge pieces is flipped, and that state is impossible to fix by regular cube moves.
Solving the cube as far as it can go should take care of both issues at the same time; swapping stickers on a nearly solved cube so that it becomes completely solved avoids any complications with the least effort.
